# Usage of pm.se chat for knowledge & event sharing?

Tags: discussion, chat

As someone who likes to attend meetups and get to know about nice videos & workshops to get up to speed with the latest around management & leadership, I've always struggled to know how to be notified in a non-intrusive way about news.

Considering it's also on community benefit to attract more talent, I was wondering if using pm.se chat for sharing such content could be a thing.
There's a session today hosted by one of our members so I believe it's a perfect moment to experiment with that. Details on chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56479/pmse-lounge

If there are other (more consolidated) ways the community get to know about such events, I believe it'd worth share on answers too.